# Where do I report superuser site bug?

Tags: discussion

Where do I report a bug I find on the superuser site (it's just a minor one)? I only found a help center entry for [security vulnerability](https://superuser.com/help/security-reports). Maybe it's one of the cases where I'm just too stupid to do the right search?! I imagine I just use the "bug" tag, and write it in here, am I correct?

Comment: Yes. The SE staff monitor all metas for bug tags. You can edit your question and report the bug here, adding the bug tag.

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you! how come this is not documented in the help center, or didn't I search right?

Comment: I don't think it is the help system ...

Comment: @DavidPostill ok, then maybe I should leave the question intact, and start another one for the bug? Maybe another user will have the same question.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I report a bug related to Stack Exchange?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/188266)

Comment: Technically yes, but the question doesn't come up if you search on superuser meta, or does it? Well now there is a link thanks to your comment?!

Comment: This is explained in [What's Meta?](https://superuser.com/help/whats-meta) on meta's help center (the "?" button on the top bar)